# ECS, meaning of memoryReservation in task definition

Tags: amazon-ecs

I'm having hard time understanding `memoryReservation` in ECS task definition.

> The soft limit (in MiB) of memory to reserve for the container. When
>   system memory is under contention, Docker attempts to keep the
>   container memory to this soft limit; however, your container can
>   consume more memory when needed, up to either the hard limit specified
>   with the memory parameter (if applicable), or all of the available
>   memory on the container instance, whichever comes first.

So what's the consequence of setting this value?

My uwsgi is getting killed because of memory, and I wonder if changing this value would help.

Answer (score 3):

seems like you have set `memory` parameter somewhere in the task definition level or in the container level, both have a big difference.

**Memory**

The amount (in MiB) of memory to present to the container. If your container attempts to exceed the memory specified here, **the container is killed**.

**MemoryReservation**

The soft limit (in MiB) of memory to reserve for the container. When system memory is under heavy contention, Docker attempts to keep the container memory to this soft limit. However, your **container can consume more memory**.

So the best option is to specify the MemoryReservation only, it will help to avoid killing your container if that limit reached.

> For example, if your container normally uses 128 MiB of memory, but
>   occasionally bursts to 256 MiB of memory for short periods of time,
>   you can set a memoryReservation of 128 MiB, and a memory hard limit of
>   300 MiB. This configuration would allow the container to only reserve
>   128 MiB of memory from the remaining resources on the container
>   instance, but also allow the container to consume more memory
>   resources when needed.

[aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html)

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you haven't specified `memory` parameters inside the task definition, then `memoryReservation` will be used to subtract memory from container instance and will be allocated for running the task. However, if you have specified `memory` parameter then it will be used to subtract that much memory from the container instance. If you're setting both parameters, then you're required to specify `memory` and `memoryReservation` parameters such that `memory` > `memoryReservation`. As you must have understood from the doc, `memory` => `hard limit` and `memoryReservation` => `soft limit`. `soft limit` is like reservation and `hard limit` is like the boundary. When your container is under heavy load or contention and requires more memory that `soft limit` it is allowed to consume upto `hard limit` of memory after which you might see getting the container killed.

You can try increasing these limits to see if all goes stable and OOM doesn't kill your uwsgi. But also be cautious of any memory leaks inside your code.

Comment: So specifying soft limit = 1Mb or 1GB means nothing when you dont have hard limit? ..

Comment: I haven't said that. Specifying soft limit will always reserve that much memory for you.

Comment: yeah, so .. I'm not sure if increasing soft limit helps me to prevent task getting killed because of out of memory..